# LSI Megaraid 150-6 as regular SATA controller

Tags: raid, storage, sata, lsi, megaraid

I have an old but reliable server board that does not have any SATA ports on it.
Also i have LSI Megararaid 150-6 (with latest firmware) which i want to use as ordinary "dumb" SATA controller.

I don't want to use any RAID functionality of the controller but just expose physical drives connected to its ports to the operatig system (FreeBSD 9.2 at the moment, three 1TB drives connected to the controller).

Is that possible? Which configuration options in the LSI BIOS should i set?

Comment: For ZFS purposes?

Comment: ewwhite: I'm going to build a software RAID5 but haven't decided yet which filesystem to choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i ended up contacting LSI support and they advised me to create a separate RAID0 arrays, one HDD in each.
Each array is exposed to the system as amrd0, amrd1, amrd2 and you can treat them as common HDD's. Weird but it seems to be the only way to use LSI150-6 as a basic SATA controller.

Comment: Yes, this is how LSI does JBOD.